# Calculating $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi/6^+}\frac{|1-2\sin x|}{4\cos^2 x-3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm finding this limit problem confusing.

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6^+}\frac{|1-2\sin x|}{4\cos^2 x-3}.$$

The answer is $\dfrac{-1}{2}$.

I tried the $1 - \sin^2x$ but I keep getting $1$ as my answer. What I did was cancel out the $\sin x$ with $\sin^2x$ then plugged in the limit. I'm doing it wrong so I need more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi^+}{6}}\frac{2\sin x-1}{1-4\sin^2x}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{2\cos x}{-4\sin(2x)}\tag{Using L'Hospital}$$

$$RHL=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Edit: Without L'hospital, factorize and proceed
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{2\sin x-1}{(1-2\sin x)(1+2\sin x)}$$

Comment: where is the '-3' in the denominator ???????

Comment: It flew into ashes. Note: $4  \cos^2 x -3=1-4\sin^2x$@j.doe

Comment: how and why did you switch around the  1 - 2sinx in the numerator to ....2sinx -1

Comment: As i took Right hand limit, at that time $2 \sin x>1$ thus we reached the condition where $|\alpha|$ where $\alpha <0$ thus we place $-\alpha$.@j.doe

Comment: wait what does 'a' represent and how did it go to a<0

Comment: @j.doe I recommend you read this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties